# Меняется протокол в относительных ссылках

Tags: html, html5, веб-программирование, http

У меня есть сайт (бэк на express), на нём есть относительные ссылки на собственные страницы. Например вместо `http://site.ru/css/style.css` используется `/css/style.css`. И проблема в том, что браузер пытается получить доступ к ресурсу через https вместо http. То есть ссылка  `/css/style.css` превращается в `https://site.ru/css/style.css`, а не `http://....`. Возможно ли как-то сказать браузеру, какой протокол использовать?

Вот инклуды:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch- 
icon.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon- 
32x32.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon- 
16x16.png" />
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/header.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/common.css" />
```

Comment: Именно https и нужно как бы использовать.

Comment: Если браузер пытается использовать https, значит ссылка на текущую страницу и так является https. А если текущая страница http, значит ссылки на самом деле не относительные, а вы что-то где-то не то увидели

Comment: Вот сайт http://armellobot.ru/

Comment: В консоли отображается, что ресурс не найден и если навести на ссылку мышь там будет https

Comment: Указанный вами сайт отправляет заголовок HSTS, который говорит о том, что нужно обязательно использовать https — вот поэтому браузер и использует https. Если вам не нужен https, то уберите HSTS

Comment: @andreymal Отключил все заголовки, которые ставил helmet, в том числе и hsts - безрезультатно

Comment: А теперь надо в браузере удалить всю информацию об этом сайте, чтобы он забыл ранее запомненный заголовок HSTS

Comment: Спасибо большое, совсем забыл про кэш